# WP query to get posts from category ( not child of it )

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this $args for WP_Query:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'estructura',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => '12',
            ),
        )
    );
```

Witch returns the posts tagged with the category 12 or tagged with the childs categories ( of 12 )

I want only the ones tagged with category 12,

How can I prevent to return the childs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using the `include_children` option

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'estructura',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    =>  $tax_id, // 12
            'include_children' => false
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `tax_query`, it's getting all of the children as they have the parent's url in their URL (e.g. website.com/category_name/child_1/).

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 12 ) );
```

This should work fine. Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters